# Kill a hanging process which is in kernel mode

Tags: process, aix, signals, debugging

I had a process attached to a debugger session, and, by mistake, I kill the debugger. Now, I'm trying to kill the process I was debugging but I can't because it's probably in Kernel Mode now, maybe waiting from some resource that cannot be provided because the debugger is no longer in place.

So, how can I solve the situation without restarting the server?

The OS is AIX 6.1 and the debugger is dbx.

Comment: What is the status of the process: `ps axu` ?

Comment: @user1794469 :o The process is gone!!! I don't know what the hell happened. The status was `T`, so stopped. Unless there is some kind of timeout, I don't understand how the process is no longer there, unless another user of the server has been able to kill it somehow.

Comment: @user1794469 Or some timeout happened to move the process out of kernel mode and then being killed by pending signals.